# Corrupt mysql system tables

Tags: mysql, database, corruption

I am having issues with the columns_priv table in the mysql system database.  I cannot add new users currently.

I have tried repairing it using `mysqlcheck --auto-repair --all-databases --password` but I get the following output:

```
mysql.columns_priv
Error    : Incorrect file format 'columns_priv'
error    : Corrupt
```

Is there any other way to repair this table, or how do I go about replacing it with a blank table?  What would I lose by doing that?

Thank you

Edit (Additional Info)
`mysqld` is currently using 100% cpu constantly.

Looking at `show processlist`, I get:

```
mysql> show processlist;
+-----+------------------+-----------+-------+---------+------+-------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Id  | User             | Host      | db    | Command | Time | State             | Info                                                                                                 |
+-----+------------------+-----------+-------+---------+------+-------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|   5 | debian-sys-maint | localhost | mysql | Query   | 1589 | Opening tables    | ALTER TABLE tables_priv
   MODIFY Column_priv set('Select','Insert','Update','References')
     COLL |                                                                        |
| 752 | root             | localhost | NULL  | Query   |    0 | NULL              | show processlist                                                                                     |
+-----+------------------+-----------+-------+---------+------+-------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Restore from backup? Restart from scratch with all system tables using [`mysql_install_db`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-install-db.html) and re-add all users again. And make sure you find the cause for this corruption - this should not happen.

Comment: The cause was probably due to the SAN going offline / read only.  The server became unresponsive and the datacentre did a reboot after the SAN recovered.  I'll attempt to restore a backup and hope for the best.

Comment: Dropping the table and restoring it from a backup worked ok :)